# Create a nested list object with an arbitrary depth

Tags: python

I want to create a nested list object. In this way, the user enters a positive integer, then add empty lists to the initial list, equal to the number entered by the user. The second list should be added to the first list, the third list should be added to the second list, the fourth list should be added to the third list, and so on.

How can I do this using Python?

Example in the picture:

[image]

Comment: _I tried to do it with for loop_ Show us what you tried.

Comment: Is your desired result actually a string with the value `"[[[[[ ]]]]]"`? Or an empty list within a list within a list ...

Comment: `for _ in range(4): A = [A]` should do it.  What did you try?

Comment: Please update your question with this code that you tried.

Comment: Please don't use comments. [edit] the question with the relevant information

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74678460/edit) your question to include this code you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = []
for _ in range(x):
    a = [a]
```